# Ribbon Control for VS2013

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, ribbon

I'm working on a WinForms C# application and need to implement Ribbon style control such as the one found in MS Office Word as an example, where you can hide the ribbon and its controls.

I can't find the ribbon control in VS2013, is it a 3rd party control? If that's the case do you know which one is best?

Thank you,

Matias.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Janus Systems](http://www.janusys.com/controls/) they currently support office 2010 visual style controls. They Will release a new version soon with new styles. I've been working with the controls a few years now. They offer great out of the box functionality.